# Android wear: CardScrollView not working as documented

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to use the CardScrollView and CardFrame as documented in the developer site. 
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/cards.html

Card is appearing, but when I add large text for the second textview (example from above link), card is shown as expanded by default and its not scrolling , also bottom texts are cropped out. Did anyone faced the same issue or have a working solution please share

--Thanks